# Feather.js + Sequelize + postgres 11 : How to patch a jsonb column?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, feathersjs

I would like to update several row of my db with the same object.
let say I have a column customText type jsonb which contains an array of object

here my sequelize model :

```
  customText: {
    type: DataTypes.JSONB,
    allowNull: true,
    field: "custom_text"
  }
```

Now from client I send an object:

```
const obj = {}        
const data = {
          textid: "d9fec1d4-0f7a-2c00-9d36-0c5055d64d04",
          textLabel: null,
          textValue: null
        };

    obj.customText = data
    api.service("activity").patch(null, obj).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Like the [documentation from feathers.js](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/databases/common.html#adapter-update-id-data-params) said if I want to replace multiple record, I send an id equal to null.

So now here come the problem, if I do that my column customText will contain the new object only but I want an array of object, so I want to push the new data in the array. How can I patch the data?

My guess is to use a [hook in feathers.js](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/hooks.html#quick-example)  and a [raw query with sequelize](https://devdocs.io/sequelize/manual/raw-queries). But I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure of my answer but this hook work :

```
module.exports = function() {
  return async context => {
    debugger;
    const sequelize = context.app.get("sequelizeClient");
    const customText = JSON.stringify(context.data.customText[0]);
    console.log(customField);
    let query =
      "UPDATE activity SET custom_text = custom_text || '" +
      customText +
      "' ::jsonb";
    console.log(query);

    await sequelize
      .query(query)
      .then(results => {
        console.log(results);
        context.results = results;
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));

    return context;
```

I still have a problem because after this hook in feathers, the patch continue so it will update my db again.. so i put a [disallow() hook](https://hooks-common.feathersjs.com/hooks.html#disallow).

Also, with this hook i lost the abilities [to listening to event](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/client/socketio.html#listening-to-events)

Also i have a concern with the query, i'm not sure if it's better to use :jsonb_insert over ||